# Why do the police announce the time when they arrest somebody?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, police, arrest

In the U.K. when police arrest someone, they seem to first announce the current time in military/24 hour format, and then they declare the reason or grounds for the arrest. Declaring the grounds for the arrest makes perfect sense. But what is the reason for the obligatory talking clock routine?

Comment: public announcements or to a person they arrest?

Comment: @Trish who said anything about public announcements?

Comment: @Seekinganswers you used the term "announce". Trish is asking for clarification as to whether you meant a public announcement, or a statement to the person they are arresting.

Comment: It was (is) decidedly unspecific.

Comment: For reference, it would be nice to add a quote on what an officer precisely said to the person being arrested.

Comment: "Decidedly unspecific" makes this too vague. - there are clear legal differences between "It is 14:01, I arrest you for jaywalking" and the announcement 5 hours later "at 14:01 police forces arrested someone for jaywalking".

Comment: Okay I’m thinking more of the former type. Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. I’m not sure if there are requirements for the announcement to be loud and clear and audible for anyone present to be able to hear or if it is just for the arrested person to be able to hear. But on second thought it is usually apparently addressed to the arrested person: often the script goes “the time is 12:34, you are under arrest on suspicion of [X offence],” so it is grammatically addressed in the second person.

Comment: My original question was asked deliberately to allow for the aforementioned ambiguity which I’d then perceived however the more that I think about it the less ambiguous it seems to be.

Answer (score 13):

There are clear rules about the length of time a suspect can be held.
The UK government says in
[Being arrested: your rights](https://www.gov.uk/arrested-your-rights/how-long-you-can-be-held-in-custody)

> **How long you can be held in custody**
>
> The police can hold you for up to 24 hours before they have to charge you with a crime or release you.
>
> They can apply to hold you for up to 36 or 96 hours if you’re suspected of a serious crime, such as murder.
>
> You can be held without charge for up to 14 days If you’re arrested under the Terrorism Act.

So it is vital information for interested parties, such as family and legal representatives.

Comment: One of your better answers, I’ll have to say. And it makes good sense, but could nonetheless in my estimation be improved with references to official sources that directly stipulate the announcement or even connect it with the 24 hour time limit. Perhaps there is something in the PEACE code of practice etc, or even the PACE act itself for that matter.